# JSON::Schema::ValidationError: The property '#/' of type any did not match the following type: object

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-5, jsonschema

I use `json-schema` to validate.When I run these commands:

```rb
params = ActionController::Parameters.new({"name": "John Doe","age": 30})
create_schema = {
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "age": {
      "type": "integer"
    }
  }

JSON::Validator.validate!(create_schema, params)
```

In rails 4, it will be returns true,
but in rails 5, it will raise the error:
`JSON::Schema::ValidationError: The property '#/' of type any did not match the following type: object`

I found that `In Rails 4, the ActionController::Parameters object is a hash. In Rails 5, the ActionController::Parameters object is a subclass of Hash called ActionController::Parameters::UnboundedHash.`

How do you validate here? Thank you.